# Importing Python module from Bash

Tags: python, linux, bash, alias

I am launching a Python script from the command line (Bash) under Linux. I need to open Python, import a module, and then have lines of code interpreted. The console must then remain in Python (not quit it). How do I do that?

I have tried an alias like this one:

```
alias program="cd /home/myname/programs/; python; import module; line_of_code"
```

But this only starts python and the commands are not executed (no module import, no line of code treated).

What is the proper way of doing this, provided I need to keep Python open (not quit it) after the script is executed?
Many thanks!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

An easy way to do this is with the "code" module:

```
python -c "import code; code.interact(local=locals())"
```

This will drop you into an interactive shell when code.interact() is called.  The `local` keyword argument to `interact` is used to prepopulate the default namespace for the interpreter that gets created; we'll use `locals()`, which is a builtin function that returns the local namespace as a dictionary.

Your command would look something like this:

```
python -c "import mymodule, code; code.interact(local=locals())"
```

which drops you into an interpreter that has the correct environment.

Comment: This only works halfway. I added my import module, either before or after 'import code' but when in the interactive python console, my module is not available.

Comment: I think the code module can do what you want, but you have to bootstrap the environment like this:
    python -c "import sys, code; code.interact(local=locals())"
This drops me to a command shell that lets me do:
    >>> print sys.argv[0]
Is this closer to what you're trying to do?

Comment: Great! This does the job for me. My own module is now also loaded (import sys, code, mymodule;...) Cheers

Comment: Nice! What if I also want to execute some code?
`python -c "import mymodule, code; code.interact(local=locals()); print('ciao')"` would not work..

Comment: @Alain1405 - once you call `code.interact(...)`, you're in the interactive session. If you want to run code before you get into your interactive session, you'll have to put it before the call to `code.interact(...)`. If you want to execute code after the interactive session ends, but before the interpreter exits, you can exit the interpreter with `CTRL-d` on Linux, or `CTRL-z + Enter` on Windows, and you should see your 'ciao' message  on the terminal.

Answer (score 9):

use a subroutine instead of alias

```
callmyprogram(){
  python -i -c "import time;print time.localtime()"
}
callmyprogram
```

Comment: @ghostdog74 I never use a subroutine before. Where do I put this? In the .bashrc file? (.bash_bashrc because I'm using Linux Mint) How do I then launch it? Thx.

Comment: you can put it in any script. since you have `.bash_bashrc`, you can put it there. if you want to use the subroutine, just do a `source .bash_bashrc`

Comment: + for the combination of `-i` and `-c`, which solves the OP's problem. While putting something in a function never hurts (for added flexibility), _an alias would work equally well here_.
A note on Bash terminology: 'subroutine' is used as an umbrella term for both _shell functions_ and _sourced scripts_; therefore, it's better to call this a _[shell] function_.

Answer (score 3):

Example:

```
python -c "import time ; print 'waiting 2 sec.'; time.sleep(2); print 'finished' "
```

Comment: @Karol Thx, but I must remain within Python in the console since this is an interactive script. I edited the question to add this.

Comment: If you need to remain 'within' python, start the interpreter with the `-i` flag.

Comment: I tried with the -i (with or without c-) but i get a: 'python: can't open file 'import module': [Errno 2] No such file or directory'

Comment: @Morlock: What does it mean when you say "since this is an interactive script"? Normally, you can have interactive scripts without being in the console.

Comment: @Dennis Williamson I wish to open a console, type 'myprogram', and then Python opens, imports a given module, maybe a line or 2 of script, and finally remains in the Python console and gives back the hand to the user. The user is now ready to use the program, from the console, with the '>>>' Python prompt. Cheers